# What is the difference between Disposing Element in Javascript and Removing using Jquery Remove Method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a image tag in javascript for some processing, after that when i complete the processing i need to remove/dispose the object. i use the jquery remove method to remove the object. what is the difference of jquery remove method and assigning null to the object? which should i use.?

```
function processInfo()
{
var img = new Image();
/*
some processing.
*/

// at this line i need to remove/dispose the object.

$(img).remove();
}
```

Comment: whether the object is added to the dom? is there any jQuery event handlers/data associated with the element

Comment: well object is added to the dom... no data/handlers associated with the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery `remove` removes element reference from DOM. If your javascript reference is scoped to `processInfo` function you don't need to do anything else, garbage collector will remove this ref automatically. Even more, if you don't add your `img` to DOM `remove` call also not necessary.

Comment: well the element is added to the dom.

Comment: So `remove` call is enough unless you don't have reference to it somewhere in global scope.